# How to engineer screen sharing in react.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, screen

It seems to me that building a screen sharing app in react.js should be easier than other frameworks. Because react.js only updates the dom when something changes, it seems to me that you could quite easily send the entire webpage's HTML to another browser (using a node server or other server), and then trap the changes to the webpage, determine if they are in the area you are sharing, and just send the changes to the other browser.

Has anyone attempted this approach? Any examples or discussions that might be relevant?

Another approach might be to override the basic react component and add a "watched" state to it that would call a method to send the changed HTML when the component was updated...

Both methods seem feasible enough... any implementations already? Which approach would you take? Why?